# How to measure first frame of Android Jetpack Compose view?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

We're aimed to build performance monitoring in our compose page. One of these monitorings is to measure how long we'll reach the first frame from app boot. For example, we used LazyColumn in our MainActivity, then we'd like to measure when the first item in LazyColumn will be shown.

In Android native development, we can use something like `onGlobalLayout` to measure how long we'll reach the first visible view. But in Jetpack Compose, we didn't find any useful API. We found `DisposableEffect`, but I don't think it's designed for this.

BTW, we want to collect online metrics from real users not local or CI tests. (So I think Macrobenchmark is not suitable for us)